# JQuery .focusout does not work with :input selector

Tags: jquery, events

I'm trying set setup a search refinement tool that will search as soon as the user toggles to another field, as long as the field losing focus has a value change.  I thought I could use the `.focusout` event.  The problem I am having is the event only seems to fire as expected if I make the selector `*` like the example below

JQuery v1.7.2

```
/* this works! */
    $('*').focusout(function () {
        alert('Handler for .focus() called.');
    });
```

But, as soon as I change the selector to anything else I've tried so far...The event will not fire.

I've tried.

- `:input`
- `#searchForm` <-- the form id
- `#YearBuiltTo` <-- the field id

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I've tested this in IE9 and Chrome

Comment: I cannot repro this on Firefox. What browser are you using? Does the code in your question reside in a `ready` handler?

Comment: This is probably because you are calling this when the only elements that exist are `html` and `head`, so you are attaching it to `html` and `head` elements with `"*"`.

Comment: seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/U2n8w/

Comment: I'm calling this as part of the document.ready() handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some garbage js code in my _Layout.cshtml.  I had pasted into the layout and then forgot about it.  It was throwing errors that were causing any more javascript to not execute correctly from my Search.cshtml page.

I removed the garbage code, and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try using [.blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) instead of .focusout

ie. $("#YearBuiltTo").blur();

Comment: really? maybe i'm misunderstanding what the op wants but this works: http://jsfiddle.net/fgALF/

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. i read that '<-- the form id' when it said '<-- the field id'